# Express cardinality of index set satisfying conditions

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, logical-constraints

I have two sets of binary variables $x_{i,j}$ and $y_{i,k}$, where $i, j, k$ ranges over some index set $I,J,K$, which satisfies the constraint $\sum_j x_{i,j} = 1$, $\sum_{k} y_{i, k} = 1$. How do I express the cardinality of the set $S_k := \{j: x_{i, j} =1 \text{ and } y_{i, k} = 1 \text{ for some } i\}$ for each $k$? I am trying to minimize an expression which is a linear combination of the cardinalities $|S_k|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

- $z_{ijk} = 1$ iff. $x_{ij} = 1 \wedge y_{ik} = 1$ $\forall i \in I, j \in J, k \in K$; And
- $s_{kj} = 1$ iff. $\exists_{i \in I} (z_{ijk} = 1)$ $\forall j \in J, k \in K$.

Then:

$z_{ijk} \geqslant x_{ij} + y_{ik} - 1$ $\forall i \in I, j \in J, k \in K$.

$x_{ij} \geqslant z_{ijk}$ $\forall i \in I, j \in J, k \in K$.

$y_{ik} \geqslant z_{ijk}$ $\forall i \in I, j \in J, k \in K$.

$s_{kj} \geqslant z_{ijk}$ $\forall i \in I, j \in J, k \in K$.

$\sum_{i \in I} z_{ijk} \geqslant s_{kj}$ $\forall j \in J, k \in K$

$S_k = \sum_{j \in J} s_{kj}$ $\forall k \in K$

Let me know case you see any mistake.

UPDATE: Thanks to @RobPratt.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks for the correction, let me know case there is still a missing point.

Comment: Thank you and @RobPratt!

Answer (score 3):

You can strengthen the formulation given by @Matheus Diógenes Andrade by replacing the $x_{ij} \ge z_{ijk}$ and $y_{ik} \ge z_{ijk}$ constraints.  We are given
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_k y_{ik} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Now multiply \eqref{1} by $y_{ik}$ and \eqref{2} by $x_{ij}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{ij}y_{ik} &= y_{ik} &&\text{for all $i$ and $k$} \tag3\label3 \\
\sum_k y_{ik}x_{ij} &= x_{ij} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \tag4\label4
\end{align}
Now replace the product $x_{ij} y_{ik}$ with $z_{ijk}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_j z_{ijk} &= y_{ik} &&\text{for all $i$ and $k$} \tag5\label5 \\
\sum_k z_{ijk} &= x_{ij} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \tag6\label6
\end{align}

This change yields a formulation that is both tighter and smaller.